# Remove space from String

Tags: c#

I have a lot of strings that look like this:

```
current            affairs
```

and i want to make the string be :

```
current affairs
```

i try to use `Trim()` but it won't do the job

Comment: Just for your future reference, Trim() removes spaces from the beginning and end of the string only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regex can do the job

```
string_text = Regex.Replace(string_text, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Or, as a faster variant: `Regex.Replace(myString, "\\s{2,}", "")` so you don't replace single spaces by themselves. Makes a difference of about 30 % in my test here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions for this, see [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx):

```
var normalizedString = Regex.Replace(myString, " +", " ");
```

If you want all types of whitespace, use `@"\s+"` instead of `" +"` which just deals with spaces.

```
var normalizedString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression.

```
yourString= Regex.Replace(yourString, @"\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
public string RemoveMultipleSpaces(string s) 
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+", " ");
}
```

After:

```
string s = "current            affairs  ";
s = RemoveMultipleSpaces(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex here is the way,

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @”\s+”, ” “);
```

This will removes all whitespace characters including tabs, newlines etc.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to split the whole string and then apply trim to each item.

```
  string [] words = text.Split(' ');
  text="";
  forearch(string s in words){
    text+=s.Trim();
  }
  //text should be ok at this time
```